# How can you pass output of find command to a diff command with multiple files?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, diff

I find 5 files ending with .csv. Now I want to compare the content of these files using diff command. How can I perform both actions in one command on a Linux terminal on bash?

I want to do something like:

```
$ find -name *.csv | diff output_of_find_command
```

And print the differences in the files. (There are 5 of them).

Comment: Normally diff expect two files or directories. And I am afraid it can\t compare 5 files (in one task). Maybe you should reconsider the way files are compared

Comment: @RomeoNinov  There are ways around the problem you point out, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` is a program to compare exactly two files. The only way I know to do an N-way `diff` is to use the command `diffuse`, not installed by default but available on all distros.

Then the resulting command will be:

```
find -name *.csv | xargs diffuse
```

Notice that `diffuse` is not suitable for scripting: it outputs the differences in a GUI, which makes it highly convenient for visual inspection.

Comment: one correction in your answer. diff expect two files OR directories. And I had no idea such software as diffuse exist :)